# ElementRef is undefined when using @ViewChild

Tags: angular, viewchild, elementref

```
import {Component, ElementRef, HostBinding, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
export class MainPage {
  constructor(
    el: ElementRef
  ) {
    this.contentElement = el.nativeElement;
  }

  contentElement = null;

@ViewChild('wrapper', { static: true }) wrapper: ElementRef;

this.size = this.wrapper.nativeElement.clientWidth - 36;
```

result

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

```
console.log(this.wrapper);
=>undefined
```

in another component , It works well without any initialization.

but I don't know why this component can't work

Comment: Is this supposed to be a component?

Comment: Can you provide snippet of your HTML template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template need to be rendered if you want your ViewChild to not be undefined. Its all about timing. You are trying to use something that doesnt exist yet which is why you are having an error.

You need to use a [lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) hook that angular provide

In your case, the view need to be rendered first so I would use `ngAfterViewInit()` with `static: false` and `ngOnInit()` with `static: true`

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.size = this.wrapper.nativeElement.clientWidth - 36;
}
```

Comment: sorry for late comment.